# Cakephp 1.3.15 é compatível com Php 5.6?

Tags: php, cakephp

Tenho um projeto em CakePhp que está na versão 1.3.15 e o manual diz que ele é compatível com PHP 4 e com o 5.
O servidor de hospedagem está com PHP 5.3.3.
Eu gostaria de saber se ele é realmente compatível com o PHP 5.6.

Comment: Sim, é compatível com php 5.6. Contudo, experimente num ambiente de testes antes de colocar num ambiente de produção.

Comment: Só uma coisa Fabricio, sendo php5.3 e é um projeto no, talvez você possa optar pelo cakephp2 que é compatível com PHP5.2.8+ (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/pt/installation.html)

Comment: Fique esperto que tem N funçõe que foram depreciadas, talvez tenha que alterar algumas delas por outras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação oficial](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Requirements.html), a versão 1.3 requer apenas que a versão do PHP seja `>= 4.3.2` , ou seja, é compatível.

Com o Daniel comentou, faça uma verificação antes em um ambiente de testes, verifique o comportamente de todos os módulos/extensões, tanto do PHP quanto do CakePHP.